# How the characters from 'g to 'z' are usefull to represent a number as String in Java (wrapper class Integer)?

Tags: java, string, integer, wrapper

In the source code of Integer.java, there is a character array.

```
/**
     * All possible chars for representing a number as a String
     */
    static final char[] digits = {
        '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
        '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
        'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
        'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
        'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
        'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
    };
```

How the alphabets 'g' to 'z' are useful to represent a number as a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent integers in any base:

- base2 = binary {0,1}
- base8 = octal {0..7}
- base10 = decimal {0..9}
- base16 = hexadecimal {0..f}
- base36 = {0..z}
- base64 = {...}
- baseN = alphabet of N symbols

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to

• Use the http://www.asciitable.com/ ascii table and do subtraction

• Correspond some of the letters to numbers (leftovers are inevitable)

• Simply add a "" (empty string) to an integer to make it a string
i.e.

```
  int X = 36;
  String Y = X +"";
```